# Complexity of java chose

Tags: java

I am not particularly familiar with the complexity of Java. I have a multiple choice question about the complexity of Java. Hope to get answers and explanations. This will help me understand better

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> void f(List<T> in) {
    boolean s;
    do {
        s = false;
        for (var i = 1; i < in.size() - 1; i += 2) {
            if (in.get(i).compareTo(in.get(i + 1)) > 0) {
                var temp = in.get(i);
                in.set(i, in.get(i + 1));
                in.set(i + 1, temp);
                s = true;
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < in.size() - 1; i += 2) {
            if (in.get(i).compareTo(in.get(i + 1)) > 0) {
                var temp = in.get(i);
                in.set(i, in.get(i + 1));
                in.set(i + 1, temp);
                s = true;
            }
        }
    } while (s);
}
```

Assuming in.get() is O(1), which of the following statements is correct?

a) The best-case time complexity of f() with in of size n is O(n).

b) The worst-case time complexity of f() with in of size n is O(n log n).

c) The worst-case time complexity of f() with in of size n is O(2 n).

d) The best-case time complexity of f() with in of size n is O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

Think about what the algorithm is doing. It's going through the vector and comparing each pair of elements [0] against [1], [2] against [3], etc. If each pair is in order, s remains false, and the algorithm does the outer loop exactly once.

If any are out of order, it's going to swap the pairs and loop.

Now, think about that. Let's say every single pair is out of order. It will swap them into order and loop. The second time through, they're in order.

I don't know why the outer loop contains the inner loop twice. The second run won't do anything. Furthermore, subsequent loops won't do anything, either, as once you've swapped pairs once, they're in order after that.

It's a stupid algorithm, by the way. The outer loop is 100% unnecessary, as is the second inner loop.

Best case: the outer loop runs once. The two inner loops each run once.
Worst case: the outer loop runs twice. The two inner loops run twice each.

But we don't normally write O(2n). That's still considered O(n).